# firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword is neither firing promise nor catching errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are using Firebase v4.12.0 and Cordova.

`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` sometimes (quite often) does not fire anything: neither a promise nor an error. It is stuck.

When it fires as expected, we can see the request to `googleapis.com`, but when it is stuck, no request is made.

This only seems to occur on iOS for a couple of weeks now. It has not occured once for the last 5 years...

Here is the code :

```
var config = {
   apiKey: "myapikey",
   authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com"
};
       
firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("email@domain.com", "password") 
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser) {
        console.log("logged !");
      } else {
        console.log("User is logged out");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error : "+JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    });
```

Is this a known issue? How can I debug and find more information about it?

Comment: Like how are you triggering it? Can you try adding it in a button click event and try clicking the button? Also try adding a return keyword before it.

Comment: Problem solved updating to the latest Firebase javascript SDK version.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).